# How do I get a scrollable title list for my scrollview?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am looking to do exactly what the latest release of the Groupon app for the iPhone does. There are why appears to be two separate scrollviews on the screen. one is the size of a navigation bar, the other fills the rest of the screen. the top scrollview has a list of titles for the different pages in the scrollview, and when you click on a title, it is centered and the corresponding page in the main scrollview is brought onto the screen. you can also slide through the titles and it will slide through the pages as you do. What i'm having trouble understanding is that the two scrollviews scroll at different rates. I've been trying to figure this out for about two days and I haven't really gotten anywhere. If you have any information on how to do this, I would greatly appreciate your help!